# ACCESSのVBAでテーブルのindex情報を取得したい

Tags: vba, ms-access

ACCESS2013のVBAについて質問です。
あるテーブルに特定の名前のインデックスがあったら処理を行う、というコードを書きたいのですが　、以下のNameという部分に対して「メソッドまたはデータ メンバが見つかりません」というエラーメッセージが表示されます。

```
If CurrentDb.TableDefs("テーブル").Indexes.Name = "インデックス名"
```

どのようにしたらエラーを解消することができますでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Indexes`オブジェクトには複数の`Index`オブジェクトが含まれているので、コレクションとして`For Each`ステートメントで扱わなければなりません。

```
For Each idx in CurrentDb.TableDefs("テーブル").Indexes

    If idx.Name = "インデックス名" Then ' TODO:処理を追加

Next
```

Comment: 理解できました！とてもわかり易い説明ありがとうございました。